# How add `include_headers => true` to csv codec for s3 output in logstash?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash

Consider logstash output configuration:

```
output {
  s3 {
    region => "${REGION}"
    bucket => "${BUCKET}"
    prefix => "${PREFIX}"
    codec => "csv"
  }
}
```

How add `include_headers` true to csv codec config?

The sample below failed:

```
codec {
    csv {
        include_headers => true
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If yes, please share it. Or is it just not working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
...
codec => csv {
 include_headers => true
}
...
```

This will support any other properties from the codec plugin too.